# Install MySQL-python using pip on QNAP TVS-473 Firmware 4.3.3.0361

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, qnap

i'm trying install MySQL-python on my NAS QNAP, but i'm getting this error "mysql_config not found", thanks for your support, below the output:

```
[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Python/src/bin] # ./pip install MySQL-python  
Collecting MySQL-python  
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip  
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:  
    sh: mysql_config: command not found  
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
      File "/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Qnapware/opt/tmp/pip-build-UYwTq4/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>  
        metadata, options = get_config()  
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config  
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")  
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config  
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))  
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found  
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Qnapware/opt/tmp/pip-build-UYwTq4/MySQL-python/
```

Even if i try with a similar package..

```
[/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Python/src/bin] # ./pip install mysqlclient  
Collecting mysqlclient  
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz  
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:  
    sh: mysql_config: command not found  
    Traceback (most recent call last): 
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>  
      File "/share/MD0_DATA/.qpkg/Qnapware/opt/tmp/pip-build-lOv7DC/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module> 
        metadata, options = get_config()  
      File "setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config  
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")  
      File "setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config 
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))  
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found
```

Pip command is failing with above error trace.

---

SOLVED:
I found that after install Python 2.7 via QPKG, the path to this one its different to the stock Pyhton, using ./pip inside this QPKG and using mysql-connector==older version, was installer without problem.

Comment: what is the base OS ?

Comment: QNAP QNAP TVS-473 Firmware 4.3.3.0361 based on Linux as i know

Comment: is it ubuntu or centOS/redhat  ?

Comment: Well it's a QNAP NAS with QTS 4.3

Comment: Hi, can you give more detail on "using ./pip inside this QPKG and using mysql-connector==older version"? I am facing the same issue and I use the pip from Python 2.7 QPKG. But I don't know how to "using mysql-connector==older version". Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: @ChrisWang i refer to using an older version of mysql-connector i don't have errors during installation